# How to specify slave.jar compatible jdk version in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

My maven project have a hard dependency on jdk1.7.
I have Jenkins(2.89.4) instance which has jdk 1.8.
When I try to connect to slave which(specifying jdk 1.7 in this slave config), launch agent is failing with error below

```
   Starting slave process: cd "/jenkins" && /opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java  -jar slave.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hudson/remoting/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
    Slave JVM has terminated. Exit code=1
```

Launch agent is successful if this slave has JDK 1.8 installed. But, in this case, my maven build is failing as my maven project have a hard dependency on JDK 1.7.

I was wondering if there is a way to specify slave.jar which is compatible with jdk 1.7 in Jenkins instance

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reconfiguring the agent or messing around with the `slave.jar`, you can configure the job to use a specific version of the JDK.

One way to do that is by using the Jenkins Global Tool Configuration. Here's a basic walkthrough of setting it up with the Oracle JDK:

1. Browse to http://JENKINS_HOME/configureTools/ (or **Manage Jenkins** -> ** Configure Global Tools**)
2. Click on the **JDK installations...** button
3. Click on **Add JDK**
4. Input a name (something like `JDK 1.7`)
5. Choose the appropriate version of the JDK from the dropdown list (like **Java SE Development Kit 7u80**)
6. Check the box **I agree to the Java SE Development Kit License Agreement**

   - This box **MUST** be checked to perform the download automatically
7. Click **Save** at the bottom of the page
8. Browse to **Configure** your Maven project
9. Look for the **JDK** dropdown in the general configuration section (will be shortly before Source Code Management)
10. Choose your newly configured `JDK 1.7` from the dropdown
11. **Save**

Now, when you run your job, it will automatically download, install, and use the `7u80` JDK.

If you already have the JDK installed on the agent (or want to use something other than the Oracle JDK): back in the **Global Tool Configuration** section, there's an **Add Installer** button.

- **Label**: *Leave blank*
- **Command**: `:`

  - Yes, that's just the no-op colon. From the help: "The command will always be run, so it should be a quick no-op if the tool is already installed."
- **Tool Home**: `/opt/jdk1.7.0_80`